# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, spotify, react-native-ios

I'm trying to use [this Spotify SDK integration](https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify) for React Native in my iOS project.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SPTAudioStreamingController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTSpotify.a(RCTSpotify.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SPTAuth", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTSpotify.a(RCTSpotify.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SPTDiskCache", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTSpotify.a(RCTSpotify.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SPTRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTSpotify.a(RCTSpotify.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The section on Architectures in the `RCTSpotify.xcodeproj` in the Libraries folder looks like all the others, I can't find anything about x86_64, and this error has never previously appeared in the project.

[image: RCTSpotify.xcodeproj architecture section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll up and check and see if there's another error right before that says something like this:

`warning: skipping file '[FOLDER_PATH]/node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK' (unexpected file type 'folder' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)`

If that's the case, you did like me and followed the README directly. What you actually want to do is add three frameworks from *within that folder*, not just the `SpotifySDK` folder.

They are `SpotifyMetadata.framework`, `SpotifyAuthentication.framework`, and `SpotifyAudioPlayer.framework`. If you add those three in, then it should work. They within the `/node_modules/rn-spotify-sdk/ios/external/SpotifySDK/` folder.

Should end up looking like this:

[image: this]

Comment: I can't fully validate this answer, I got it going through a kludge that I no longer have access to, but it looks like it does what the kludge did in an uglier way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the SDK you are trying to use is built for real device not simulator. Please, check.

Comment: The docs suggest that it should run in the simulator, is there a way to check this definitively?

Comment: you can run on a real device first.